# Lucene dependency issue

Tags: java, search, lucene

I am new to using lucene for indexing and searching. I found some example codes for indexing objects and search in them. The problem was with the lucene libs that are imported. I downloaded the lucene 4.3.1 version,still few methods like getindexwriter(boolean) in the example code seam to be not found in indexwriter class of the lucene lib.

Platform: Netbeans IDE, though not all the jars are needed,i added all the jars to the classpath of the project. Still have the issue.

Comment: provide some code example and screenshot of your compiled-time library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without some code it's difficult to say precisely what is wrong, but I suspect your example was not built for Lucene 4.x.  Lucene changed significant from 3.6 to 4.0, so examples writer using 3.6 or before, very often will not work.

Many examples and tutorial for 4.0 exist, such as:

- http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_1/demo/overview-summary.html#overview_description
- http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html

---

I'm pretty sure I found your example: http://oak.cs.ucla.edu/cs144/projects/lucene/

As far as getIndexWriter(), that's a part of the `Indexer` class included with the tutorial.  I believe you have entered your code incorrectly or something, from the error you describe.

However, this is, indeed, not designed to work with Lucene 4.x (it was created 7 years ago by the look of it, long before Lucene 4), so even if you fix that error, it still will certainly take some work to update it for use on the more recent version of Lucene.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The example i used was realy old and it works only with lucene 2.2 version. I tried it with that and evrytng is fine,but thats very out dated.